# Few history entries are not destroyable on Firefox (it might be a bug). Does a workaround exists?

Tags: firefox, history

I can clear the last hour or day of my `Firefox Quantum 68.9.0esr (64 bits)` history on `Debian 10`. But attempting to clear it all has no effect.

I searched why and removed on the history windows all the entries one by one. It's not possible : among them, seven are not destroyable : a delete has no effect on them, they stay there.

It appears to me a bug : maybe `Firefox` has a trouble on some records in the underlying database it uses for storing the history.

I tried to use the safe mode too, without success.

What can I also try ? Is it a way, for example, to reinitialize the Firefox tables that contains the history in the database entirely ?

Comment: What OS? What version of FF? Please [edit] and update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I typed on the url `about:support`. A page appears with a function allowing to test the integrity of the `places.sqlite` database => it was found defective.

As the history appeared to be damaged,

2. I exported the bookmarks,
3. Opened the directory where the root folders of *Firefox* are (by clicking on a button allowing this here or on the page displayed by the `about:profiles` url),
4. Exited *Firefox*.
5. I deleted the `places.sqlite` and the `favicons.sqlite` files.
6. I restarted *Firefox* who recovered all its bookmarks and got an empty history again.